# Rotated underbrace and overbrace in an exponential tower

Tags: underbrace, overbrace

I would like to typeset a tower of exponentials and have underbrace and overbrace *at an angle*, with rotated text (e.g., "r" and "k" here).  There are related questions, but none (I could see) had the underbraces *at an angle*.
[image: exponential tower]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,amsmath}
\def\rdots{\rotatebox[origin=l]{29}{$\scriptscriptstyle\ldots\mathstrut$}}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{-2.5pt}{b}{-6pt}{\tiny\rotatebox{29}{$\underbrace{\kern25pt}_k$}}{%
\stackinset{r}{4pt}{t}{-9.0pt}{\tiny\rotatebox{29}{$\overbrace{\kern15pt}^r$}}{%
  $a^{b^{c^{d^{\rdots^n}}}}$}}
\end{document}
```

[image]